# multicolumn listbox in html

Tags: html, listbox

Is there a way to create a multicolumn listbox in html that will properly align each of the columns so that everything is lined up vertically with a column header? for example:

```
Plate    State  Make     Model    Year   Color
G655555  IL     Mercury  Montago  2007   Black
G655555  IL     Ford     Windstar 2007   Grey
```

instead of

```
Plate    State  Make     Model    Year   Color
G655555  IL     Mercury  Montago  2007   Black
G655555  IL     Ford  Windstar   2007   Grey
```

I am using a listbox instead of a table because I want to be able to select the data that is being displayed. I am not sure if I can do that with a table. So either way, can someone show me how to align the listbox columns OR can I see a method of selecting items, by row instead of column, in a table.

Comment: You have a table there. Are you using the `<table>` markup?

Comment: when you say "listbox" do you mean a drop-down list (ie like a `<select>` tag) or a static list on the page (ie basically just a table)?

Comment: I don't want to use a drop-down list. I want all the data, or records shown statically on the page, but I want to be able to select a record to manipulate.

Answer (score 1):

No. Browsers prefer to match the OS on most inputs interfaces. And most browsers ignore HTML and CSS *inside* an OPTION tag. You might be able to set the font to monospace on the SELECT or OPTION tag.

I think that there may be better ways to build the UI that you want... I also have to question why someone would want to put six data fields into one form value on a list box.

If you're showing tabular data, then use a table. If you want to select a row, then add a checkbox (for multiple selections) or a radio button (for an exclusive choice) to each row.